# Ocultar consola con codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

Hola esto modificando un programa con codeblocks pero me muestra la consola lo cual no necesito. Estaba toqueteando los ajustes pero no encuentro la opción para convertirlo en una aplicación gráfica. He estado buscando y rebuscando en settings(opciones) pero no doy con la tecla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería ser tan sencillo como ir a las propiedades del proyecto, pestaña `proyect options` y en el combo `Type` elegir la opción `Aplicación GUI` (imagino que la opción que tendrás actualmente es `console`).